# Should I remove observer in applicationWillTerminate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I added this code in my AppDelegate.h file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(saveDataAndSettings)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                               object:nil];
}
```

I am usually writing this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

if I set UIViewController classes to be the observer (Non ARC).

I am wondering though, if I do it in AppDelegate, should I still insert this line:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

in the applicationWillTerminate: method.

Because the app would be terminated, does it make sense to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practical terms there is no need to do much cleanup in either `dealloc` or `applicationWillTerminate:` of the app delegate. The app process is about to go away.

Things like closing/saving files, and other similar types of cleanup should be done but there's little point in cleaning up memory or observers in a process that's about to quit.

Comment: do not worry, I usually do not post a lot of questions, but when I do, I accept great answers, and yours is really great!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using non ARC approach in youre project you should better manually deallocate reference to notification like you mention :

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```